# How can I remove a variable that contains a string?

Tags: python, string, variables, if-statement, typeerror

Here is my program that I am writing for a school project. In the last else function, you can see that I'm trying to remove the previous pizza order as the user has made a typo. However, using a simple -= grants an TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'str'. This is my first time writing anything other than in Scratch (:P) so a help would be appreciated.

```
item_names = ["0","Super Supreme\n","Meat Lovers\n","BBQ Chicken & Bacon\n",\
              "Apricot Chicken\n","Satay Chicken\n","Pepperoni Feast\n",\
              "Beef Italiano\n","Seafood Deluxe\n","BBQ Hawaiian\n",\
              "Peperoni Lover\n","Veg Supreme\n","Trio of Cheese\n",\
              "Beef Hot 'n Spicy\n","Roma\n","Hawaiian\n","Classic Cheese\n",\
              "Veg Hot 'n Spicy\n","Ham and Cheese\n","Beef and Onion\n",\
              "Margherita\n","Large Fries\n","Garlic Bread\n","Onion Rings\n",\
              "5 Spicy Chicken Wings","Dipping Sauce (","Orange Juice\n",\
              "Bottled Water\n","355ml Soft Drink (","1.5L Soft Drink ("];
item_prices = [0,10.50,10.50,10.50,10.50,10.50,10.50,10.50,10.50,8.00,8.00,\
               8.00,8.00,8.00,8.00,5.00,5.00,5.00,5.00,5.00,5.00,3.50,3.50,\
               3.50,5.00,0.50,3.50,3.50,1.90,3.90];

print('Hello and welcome to the Shinanigan Pizzary!')
start =1
while start == 1:
    menu_prompt = str(input("Would you like to open the menu? y/n\n"))
    if menu_prompt == "y":
        start =0
        menu()
        running_total =0
        running_names =''
        loop1 =1

        while loop1 == 1:
            try:
                items_number = int(input("Please insert your desired item's number\n"))

                running_total += float((item_prices[items_number]))
                running_names += item_names[items_number]
                query1 = str(input("Is that all? y/n\n\n"))
            except IndexError:
                    print("Please enter a valid item number.\n\n")

            if query1 == "y":
                loop1 =0
                print(running_names)
                print("Running total:","$",(running_total))
                print("\nThank you for coming! Your order is being made!")
            elif query1 == "n":
                print(running_names)
                print("Running total:","$",(running_total))
            else:
                running_total -=float((item_prices[items_number]))
                running_names -= item_names[items_number]
                print("Please enter 'y' or 'n'")

    elif menu_prompt == "n":
        print("Okay. Thanks for coming. See you next time.")
        break
```

Comment: You might want to make `running_names` a list which contains strings instead of a string itself. Then you can remove the item from the list easily.

Comment: Your names and prices should be grouped in tuples or create a class. Parallel arrays are bad practice. `items = [('Super Supreme', 10.50), ('Meat Lovers', 10.50), ...]` You can easily create a for loop i.e. `for name, price in items:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use str.replace to replace the string with an empty string:

```
running_names = running_names.replace(item_names[items_number],"")

In [6]: running_names = "Hawaiian\n mistake\n"

In [7]: print( running_names.replace("mistake\n",""))
Hawaiian
```

You cannot subtract two strings.

Comment: So I tried  print(running_names.replace("item_name[items_number]\n","")) and it doesn't work...

Comment: why are you putting `"item_name[items_number]\n"`, in quotes? Just do exactly as I have in my answer

Comment: No worries, you're welcoem, the `item_name[items_number]` is getting the last item added by index which is a string